# Symfony 5.2: two authenticators in one firewall

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have Symfony 5.2 project with 2 different ways to login - `form_login` and `form_login_ldap`

security.yml

```yaml
 providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: xxx

        ldap_user_provider:
            id: My\Custom\LdapUserProvider

        chain_user_provider:
            chain:
                providers: ['ldap_user_provider', 'app_user_provider']

firewalls:
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: chain_user_provider
            form_login_ldap:
                login_path: security_login_ldap
                check_path: security_login_ldap
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                dn_string: xxx
                query_string: xxx
                search_dn: xxx
                search_password: xxx
            form_login:
                login_path: security_login
                check_path: security_login
```

Everything works fine when `form_login` authenticator is commented out, but once I uncomment it the log produces next:

```
1. request.INFO: Matched route "security_login_ldap".

2. security.DEBUG: Checking for authenticator support. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticators":2} []
3. security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"} []
4. security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Ldap\\Security\\LdapAuthenticator"} []

5. security.INFO: Authenticator failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): The presented password is invalid. at  vendor/symfony/security-http/EventListener/CheckCredentialsListener.php:60)","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"} []
6. security.DEBUG: Authentication failure, redirect triggered. {"failure_path":"security_login_ldap"} []

7. security.DEBUG: The "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\FormLoginAuthenticator" authenticator set the failure response. {"authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"} []
8. security.DEBUG: The "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\FormLoginAuthenticator" authenticator set the response. Any later authenticator will not be called {"authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"} []

9. request.INFO: Matched route "security_login_ldap". ... "method":"GET"} []
```

So Symfony is going through the list of authenticators and checks which one supports this request.

Then it should report the match is found and pass data to matched authenticator, as it does when I have only LDAP: `security.INFO: Authenticator successful!`

Somehow it's not happening here (between lines 4 and 5) and it's just reporting fail from  `form_login`.

Symfony docs state I can have multiple authenticators inside one firewall. Not sure what I'm missing.

P.S. custom `ldap_user_provider` just overriding one method from original ldap provider to be able to work with specific attributes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62898066/symfony-5-1-ldap-authentication-with-entity-user-provider

Comment: @Rufinus are you pointing on something specific in that thread? I nether store LDAP users in DB nor have problems with LDAP login - it works. IT doesn't work together with entity authenticator tho.

Comment: If `Matched route "security_login_ldap"` does it really necessary to try to authenticate using `app_user_provider` and vice versa?
Anyway, It seems there is an existing user (`App\Entity\User`) in the database with empty password (`null`)

Comment: @Constantine no, there is no users inside DB and yes, it's not necessary to go through the chain of authenticators to auth only in one of them - but that's how it works on Symfony side I believe.
Another way to handle it would be to create 2 separate firewalls, but then I have to c share the context between them, since this both authorizations give access to the same areas inside the system.

Anyways, looks like a problem is with Form authenticator.

Comment: @SergeP Couple more questions. Does `App\Entity\User` implements `UserInterface` ? Is the `security_login` route overriden? And just for curiosity, if you change providers definition order will it change behavior?

Comment: @Constantine those are good questions and the ones I checked myself first :)

- Yes, UserInterface is implemented. 

- Changing order doesn't help, I tried to separate it to different firewalls, without any luck (but maybe because of other issues, outside of this scope)

- Not sure what you mean by "overridden", but in common - no, that route has only one definition.

Comment: @SergeP As BadCredentialsException is rised at https://github.com/symfony/security-http/blob/5.2/EventListener/CheckCredentialsListener.php#L60 it may only be caused if `getPassword()` of User class return `null` That's why I asked about UserInterface and nullable password in DB. :)

Now I have a mad guess that FormLoginAuthenticator receives ldap_user_provider as UserProvider and respectively `LdapUser->getPassword()` returns null. Does it?
https://github.com/symfony/ldap/blob/5.2/Security/LdapUser.php#L60

Comment: @Constantine you're absolutely right, exception is coming from that event listener and LDAP user has NULL password since we don't keep any LDAP users in DB - so we just auth them  through the LDAP .... I'm still trying to understand what's that mean and wine inside me doesn't help :)

Comment: @SergeP I'm trying to reproduce the issue https://github.com/constantable/mup Everything works ok, but one thing: I can login at `/login/ldap` using both ldap and entity, but can't login at  `/login` using any provider. Can you show your LdapUserProvider?
PS I'm completely new to ldap)

Comment: @Constantine thank you for that, yeah, I'm new in LDAP stuff too, it took me a couple of days just to understand and fix what's the other dev made wrong on the config side. You can ignore custom LdapUserProvider, I overridden it just to be able to pull from LDAP multiple attributes with the same name, like "user groups". Also I believe you can ignore differences with `/login` route and point both of them to the same route.

Comment: @Constantine That's interesting that it's working on your side tho... after your previous messages I started to play with `passwordAttribute`, to make sure the password is not coming as `null`... I'll do more tests and let you know, my arse in flame now :)

Comment: @SergeP `composer update symfony/ldap symfony/security-bundle --dry-run --with dependencies` what exact versions do you use btw?)

Comment: Privet @Constantine :) sorry, I'm late again. As far as I see in composer files the version of both packages is 5.2.12. BTW we were able toc resolve the issue using 2 different firewalls, following my original idea... but yeah, the question about 2 providers under 1 firewall is still there. And you're right, I need to do a clean test to make sure the scope is correct, I'll keep you posted :)